# CORS error with AWS API Gateway and Proxy Integration to Backend

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I set up an UI which is hosted with Cloudfront + S3, a load balancer which redirects to an API gateway which serves the backend APIs with a VPC proxy integration.

In the API gateway I enabled CORS and configured:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials    'true'  
Access-Control-Allow-Headers    'custom-header'     
Access-Control-Allow-Methods    'DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH,POST,PUT'    
Access-Control-Allow-Origin     'https://ui.mydomain'
```

I can see three requests in total in network view in browser:

1.

```
Request:
Request-URL: https://ui.mydomain/metadata
Requestmethod: GET
Statuscode: 301 Moved Permanently
Referrer-Guideline: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

2. 

```
Request:
Request-URL: https://api.mydomain/metadata
Requestmethod: OPTIONS
Statuscode: 200 OK
Referrer-Guideline: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Response:
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: custom-header
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH,POST,PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://ui.mydomain
```

3. 

```
Request:
Request-URL: https://api.mydomain/metadata
Requestmethod: GET
Statuscode: 401 Unauthorized
Referrer-Guideline: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Response: 401 Unauthorized
```

On 3rd request I get error message: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.mydomain/metadata' (redirected from 'https://ui.mydomain/metadata') from origin 'https://ui.mydomain' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Any idea how to solve this? I can confirm that the requests dont pass the API gateway, so the backend cant be the issue here.